# MinGW/msys, linker (ld.exe) not finding libpng (-lpng) even though it's installed, running xpdf configure script

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, libpng

I installed versions 1.2, 1.4, and 1.6 of libpng from source from the makefiles they include for MinGW/msys. It seemed to work - I've got the header files in various places:

- /include
- /include/libpng
- /include/libpng12
- /include/libpng14
- /local/include
- /local/include/libpng
- /local/include/libpng16

As well as library files:

- /lib/libpng.a
- /lib/libpng.dll.a
- /lib/libpng12.a
- /lib/libpng12.dll.a
- /lib/libpng14.a
- /lib/libpng14.dll.a
- /local/lib/libpng.a
- /local/lib/libpng.dll
- /local/lib/libpng16.a
- /local/lib/libpng16.dll

I call the configure script with msys's bash, and it chokes in the same place no matter what combination of include directory and library I feed it. Config.log gives me the following:

```
configure:7732: checking png.h usability  
configure:7732: gcc -c -g -O2  -I/local/include  conftest.c >&5  
configure:7732: $? = 0  
configure:7732: result: yes  
configure:7732: checking png.h presence  
configure:7732: gcc -E  -I/local/include  conftest.c  
configure:7732: $? = 0  
configure:7732: result: yes  
configure:7732: checking for png.h  
configure:7732: result: yes  
configure:7761: checking for png_write_row in -lpng  
configure:7786: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c -lpng -I/local/include  /local/lib/libpng.a -lz  >&5  
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpng  
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried every combination of include directory and library listed above, and it's the same, every time. It will be

```
configure:7786: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c -lpng -I/include/libpng  /lib/libpng.dll.a -lz  >&5  
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpng
```

or

```
configure:7786: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c -lpng -I/local/include/libpng16  /local/lib/libpng16.dll -lz  >&5  
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpng
```

or

```
configure:7786: gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2   conftest.c -lpng -I/include/libpng12  /lib/libpng12.a -lz  >&5  
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpng
```

You get the picture. I've successfully compiled several other xpdf pieces that don't require libpng. But here, I'm at a total loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add the MinGW redist to the path.
2. Ensure that the MinGW library and include paths precede those of Cygwin.  (The `png.h` header for MinGW targets is incompatible with the `png.h` header for Cygwin targets.)
3. Dynamically link libpng.  (The `mingw64-*-libpng` packages in Cygwin do not provide a static `libpng.a` library, which is unusual.)

For example,  for a 64-bit build:

```
$ export CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
$ export CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
$ export PATH="/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin:$PATH"
$ export CFLAGS="-L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include -lpng -Wl,Bdynamic"
$ export CXXFLAGS="$CFLAGS"
$ which libpng-config
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/libpng-config
$ ./configure
```

EDIT:  Adding the redist folder to the PATH before compile time, which contains the libpng.dll file, is the important non-obvious step that applies to both the Cygwin and MSYS environments.